# MongoDB write concern sync level

Tags: mysql, mongodb, database

I am trying to understand what exactly are the limitations of using MongoDB as the primary database for a project I am working on, it can be hard to wade through the crap online to properly understand how it compares to a more traditional database choice of say MySQL.

From what I understand from reading about HADR configuration of

IBM DB2 - http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ha.doc%2Fdoc%2Fc0011724.html,

MySQL - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-semisync.html

and MongoDB - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/

It seems that Replica Acknowledged http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-write-concern/ is the highest level of write concern in a replica set.

Is replica acknowledged the equivalent to the synchronous level in DB2 and Semisynchronous level in MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

No they are not.

IBM DB2 provides a way to make sure that all members of a replica set are upto speed at the same time, it is the same as MySQLs own synchronous replication. It ensures full consistentcy at all times throughout the slave set.

Semisynchronous replication again is not replica set `majority` either; from the documentation page:

> The master waits after commit only until at least one slave has received and logged the events.

But then:

> It does not wait for all slaves to acknowledge receipt, and it requires only receipt, not that the events have been fully executed and committed on the slave side.

In other words you have no idea whether or not any slaves actually performed the command. It is the same as `w:0` or "unsafe" writes in MongoDB.

With `majority` you have an idea that every member you send to has actually performed your command as can be seen by a cute little diagram in the documentation: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-write-concern/#verify-write-operations

and if that doesn't convince you then the quote:

> The following sequence of commands creates a configuration that waits for the write operation to complete on a majority of the set members before returning:

From the next paragraph should.

So MySQL semisynchronous is similar to `majority` but it isn't the same. DB2 is totally different.

The IBM documentation sums up the differences in replica/slave wirte concern quite well:

> The more strict the synchronization mode configuration parameter value, the more protection your database solution has against transaction data loss, but the slower your transaction processing performance. You must balance the need for protection against transaction loss with the need for performance.

This applies to DB2, MySQL and MongoDB alike. You must choose.

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate :) 

In an example with 2 servers a primary and slave, DB2 and MySQL both have fully synchronous modes whereby the commit will return successful only if the state of the commit was successfully applied to the primary and the slave.  

With mongoDB and 2 servers one primary and a slave if "majority" waits for the write operation to complete on a majority of the set members, does that mean it will require the two servers to successfully commit or is majority of the set members just one out of two? only the primary?

Comment: @rabs if you only have 2 servers the majority is oddly one server, the primary, but a 2 member setup is a really bad idea

Comment: I thought so, so then with a three member setup its obviously a majority of 2, and if the commit goes to 2 and the third fails how could you tell that a commit failed on one of the servers?  through the logs on the failing server? or the primary server?

Comment: @rabs getlasterror should return false in that case, there are sometimes where edge cases can trick MongoDB into thinking that a server which downs right at the correct moment is successful when it is not but this is just something that cannot be helped

Comment: Thanks heaps for your help its helped me piece more of it together :D

Comment: @rabs glad to have helped :)

Comment: @rabs oops just realised getlasterror will of course return an error not false, sorry parts of my current programming filtering into my words there :)

Comment: ok so with a w value of 3 and a member set of 3, if I don't have three successful commits I will get an error in getlasterror, if I dont get an error than it is committed to all 3 members, except for the edge cases of server down at exactly the right moment (which I would like to know more about so I'll keep reading)

Comment: @rabs indeed and also the problem with w:3 is that MongoDB WILL wait forever for a member to respond, even if it is down, it expects 3 members to come back

Comment: @rabs there has been talk about making a `whole_set` wite concern but it always comes down the same fundamental problem with distributed sets, how do you tell what's up and down and what the whole set is?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46212/discussion-between-rabs-and-sammaye)

Comment: @rabs can't really chat atm since I am actually at work